# OSError: Unable to create file (unable to open file: name = <filepath>, errno = 13, error message = 'Permission denied', flags = 13, o_flags = 302)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I don't understand what I'm missing...
I use Tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0, Keras-gpu 2.3.1, numpy 1.16.6, h5py 2.9.0, python 3.7.9.
This is how I try to save my model:

```
model_just_name = 'LSTM_FA_SpGyZ_out1_6d_dno_seq_b_p_tmm'
filepath = r'D:\test_data_pros\restructured'

model.save(model_just_name + "model.h5",
           filepath=filepath,
           overwrite=True,
           include_optimizer=True)
```

**edit:**
When using Keras 2.4.3 with Tensorflow 2.3.0 or Keras 2.3.1 with Tensorflow 2.1.0 everithing works fine. But for what I currently try to do I need the versions listed above.

Comment: Try using ```model_just_name + "/model.h5"``` or check if ```test_data_pros``` exist :)

Comment: I am seeing a similar error for tensorflow versions `2.0.7` and `2.12.0`. When I try to save to a tempfile without a suffix `with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmpfile: model.save(tmpfile.name)`, it complains that the path is not a _directory_. With `(suffix='.h5')`, I get the error from the question above... Did you resolve the root cause of keras being unable to save to a valid (temp) `.h5` file path?

Answer (score 0):

Ask administrator to give you access to "D:\test_data_pros\restructured"

Comment: so you think the error doesn't lies in my code? when using Keras 2.4.3 with Tensorflow 2.3.0 everithing works fine. But for what I currently try to do I need the versions listed above.

Comment: @Pm740 please edit your answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

if the path is a folder then it may not work. Try to give some file name.